# how to overcome twitter api rate limit?

Tags: twitter

I am writing a small app, building stats for twitter users (no of tweets, friends etc).  I am using this api

http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?user_id=12345

I can only make 150 calls per hour, which is very very small, given the size of twitter. How do companies that rely on Twitter's API manage to overcome this rate limit?

Answer (score 3):

The 150 API calls is per user per application. Larger companies likely broker deals with Twitter.

Comment: that means I can't experiment with twitter api, right?  150 is laughable limit, if one wants to do any serious data mining with twitter

Answer (score 0):

You need to get whitelisted to get a far higher rate limit. They are open to all sorts of developers, as long as you give a good reason for what you are developing:

http://twitter.com/help/request_whitelisting

Comment: ha...it says "only available to developers and to applications in production; all other requests are rejected."  this means there is no way to experiment

Comment: no, go ahead and apply, but give a very good reason on why you are doing so

Comment: I am not sure if its worthwhile to apply (I can try though).  The documentation clearly says "only for apps in production".  As a newbie just getting started, I am not sure what good reason I can give, other than "experiment and learn".   Just how do sites like tweetstats, twittercounter etc manage the limit?

Comment: How would my App be whitelisted ? I referred to the link provided by you and also searched a lot but couldn't find the process of getting whitelisted..

Answer (score -1):

You will easily get whitelisted, just apply. They will accept more or less any reasonable application, but just don't want to leave it 'wide open'. If they dont accept you, and you still want to get your hands on the data, just scrape it.

Comment: Twitter no longer provide API whitelisting: [https://support.twitter.com/entries/160385-how-do-i-get-whitelisted](https://support.twitter.com/entries/160385-how-do-i-get-whitelisted), [https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting#whitelisting](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting#whitelisting).